# Hover to continuously scroll horizontal div

Tags: jquery, scroll, hover, carousel

I'm developing an horizontal image carousel and I'd like it to continuously scroll when hovering over it, and to stop when moving the mouse out of it. The JS code uses the hover event to detect where the mouse is and to scroll to the left or to the right accordingly. I can't get it to work, though, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

[image]

JS:

```
$('.carousel-frame ul').on('hover', function(e) {
  var container = $(this).parent();
  if ((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) < container.width() / 2) {
    var direction = function() {
      container.stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: '-=600'
      }, 1000, 'linear', direction);
    }
    container.stop().animate({
      scrollLeft: '-=600'
    }, 1000, 'linear', direction);
  } else {
    var direction = function() {
      container.stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: '+=600'
      }, 1000, 'linear', direction);
    }
    container.stop().animate({
      scrollLeft: '+=600'
    }, 1000, 'linear', direction);
  }
}, function() {
    var container = $(this).parent();
    container.stop();
});
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-frame {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.carousel-frame ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
.carousel-frame li.carousel-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-frame">
  <ul>
    <li class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
    </li>
    <li class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
    </li>
    <li class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
    </li>
    <li class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
    </li>
    <li class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

FIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/btLoenzf/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi try this https://jsfiddle.net/sharmi1308/btLoenzf/2/

I have used like this

```
$('.carousel-frame ul').hover(function(e) {...
```